# How to read contents of TCP packets from Internet by java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am researching how to build an Intrusion Prevention System (IPS) application using Java, however I don't know how to redirect Internet packets from a PC to my application and read the packets. The data format I'm looking to get from the packets is similar to the data that Wireshark produces. How would I go about getting low-level packet data like this in a Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java does not have access to "raw sockets"--the kind of access you need to get the details you'd expect from a Wireshark dump or the similar.

If you need to use Java for the rest of your application, consider using [JNI](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~naras/java/course/lec5/lec5.html) (link is to a good JNI tutorial). It allows you to use C/C++/Fortran code within a Java application, so you can make system calls and get the kind of access you need.

Comment: So, if i use JNI, the application can run on android devices. can't it ?

Comment: It can run on Android devices, just make sure that whatever system calls you require are available on Android. For more information, see Google's [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will refer your suggestions.